# Need custom Drupal view displayed in header node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

For a Drupal site I'm building, I've used the Views module to create a custom view that shows the top 10 most popular taxonomy terms. I'd like this list to show up in my site's header but I'm having trouble accomplishing this. I can get the header to display a *link* to the page for the view, but haven't figured out how to actually display the *content* of the view in the header node.

Also, if there's a better way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create view with the "block" display. This block can be placed in any region using standard block/theme functionality. 
If you don't have "header" region, you can create your own. See this link for details.
https://drupal.org/node/1088718

Maybe, i do not quite understand you question (actually, phrase "header node" confused me, you mean header area/region?). If you need to display view on the node page, you can use views_attach ot eva modules.

Comment: Aha! The problem was that I created my view as a page and not as a block, so it didn't show up in the list of blocks, logically enough. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
Create a region in your theme.
Render the region on your theme page.tpl.php
Create a block display of you view and assign it to that region.

**Option 2**
You can create a view and then embed it in your theme file using views_embed_views. For details https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7

Hope this solves your problem